# Python3.x: Importing gdata throw error

Tags: python, google-people-api, google-contacts-api

People api is fetching only saved contacts while my requirement is to fetch contacts from other section as well for example (**Others**, **Frequently Contacted...**).
I found suggestions about **Contact api** but getting import error while importing gdata.[image]

Comment: Issue is here: https://github.com/google/gdata-python-client/issues/29 with some suggested alternatives.

Comment: @robert_x44 thanks for the response, I will look into the suggestion